# Should I useReducer or useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am currently learning React and Next.js, and I am wondering if it is a good practice to use a useReducer when a component's state depends on a previous state, as opposed to using just a useState. For example, I have a page with three states: 'loading', 'error', and 'success', and each state requires the page to behave differently. What would be the recommended approach in this scenario?

I have successfully implemented the desired behavior in my application and reviewed the documentation that explains the differences between using a reducer and using state to manage state in React. However, I lack the experience to know when to apply each approach.

Code

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case AXIOS_REQUEST_ACTION.PUT:
            return { isLoading: true, error: null };
        case AXIOS_REQUEST_ACTION.SCCESS:
            return { ...state, description: action.payload.data.data.description, isLoading: false };
        case AXIOS_REQUEST_ACTION.ERROR:
            return { ...state, isLoading: false, error: action.payload.data.error  };
        default:
            throw new Error('Invalid action type');
    }
}

const initState = {
    isLoading: false,
    error: null,
    description: description,
}

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initState);

const updateDescription = (changedDescription) => {
    dispatch({ type: AXIOS_REQUEST_ACTION.PUT });
    axios.put(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VARIABLE_HOST}/prediction/${clientID}/${articleID}/${year}/${quarter}/${type}`, { description: changedDescription })
        .then(response => dispatch({ type: AXIOS_REQUEST_ACTION.SCCESS, payload: response }))
        .catch(error => dispatch({ type: AXIOS_REQUEST_ACTION.ERROR, payload: error.message }));
};

const isAgreedChange = (event) => {
    setChecked(!checked);
    isAgreed = checked;
    dispatch({ type: AXIOS_REQUEST_ACTION.PUT });
    axios.put(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VARIABLE_HOST}/prediction/${clientID}/${articleID}/${year}/${quarter}/${type}/agree`, { isAgreed: !checked })
        .then(response => dispatch({ type: AXIOS_REQUEST_ACTION.SCCESS, payload: response }))
        .catch(error => dispatch({ type: AXIOS_REQUEST_ACTION.ERROR, payload: error.message }));
}
```

Comment: Do you have any existing code for this scenario, so we know what you're currently working with?

Comment: Updated my question with the code. I currently have a page that fetches data from an API. The loading state shows an animation, the success state shows the table with content, and the error state clears the table, sets loading to false and shows the error messages.

Comment: You're probably better off using suspense: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/streaming-and-suspense